# Can't access psql due to authentication fail

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying a tutorial for django that it uses postgresql but I have some issues in setting up the DB. I did change postgres password using `sudo passwd postgres` and I can login to postgres account using `su postgres` or `sudo su - postgres` but after that I can't access the postgres prompt with `pqsl`. It gives me the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I've changed the `pg_hba.conf` file too (from peer to md5) but it didn't change anything.
I've never worked with postgresql and this is my first time using it so if you need any other information please ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo passwd postgres` is for the system user postgres which is why you can su to system user postgres shell. When you are doing psql -U postgres you are logging in as database user postgres. That is a different account. It is convention that the system user the Postgres server runs as is generally called postgres. Also by convention the Postgres server database 'root/superuser' is the name of the user that the server runs as, so again generally postgres. If you want to log in as postgres user to server using password you will need to create a password for the database user postgres. To do that I would see if in pg_hba.conf the local (not localhost) line is set to `trust`. If not set it to that and and do:

`psql -U postgres -d postgres`

Do not specify a `-h`. This will connect you via a local socket. Then you can :

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-alteruser.html

`ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'your_password'`

This will create a password for `postgres` user.

FYI, you don't have to log into system user postgres account to work as postgres user in database. All you have to do is specify `-U postgres` to any of the Postgres client programs, `psql, pg_dump, etc`. This also means you can work as postgres database user on remote servers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was going crazy about this problem :-)